# js - duplicate all child nodes

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want to duplicate all child nodes in a container, and insert them in the same container.

For example, I have:

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="square red"></div>
  <div class="square green"></div>
</div>
```

And after running this JS:

```
function duplicateChildNodes (parentId){
  var parent = document.getElementById(parentId);
  NodeList.prototype.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;
  var children = parent.childNodes;
  children.forEach(function(item){
    parent.appendChild(item);
  });
};

duplicateChildNodes("container");
```

I should have:

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="square red"></div>
  <div class="square green"></div>
  <div class="square red"></div>
  <div class="square green"></div>
</div>
```

For some reason, it doesen't work. How do I solve it ?
A pen: https://codepen.io/t411tocreate/pen/gXqYWj

Comment: that dom element only exists in one place so after append it is moved to a new place, you need clone node first. ex: `var cln = itm.cloneNode(true);`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

that dom element only exists in one place so after append it is moved to a new place (in your case it is removed and appended to the same place)

You need clone node first. ex: `var cln = itm.cloneNode(true);`

check the updated example below:

```js
function duplicateChildNodes (parentId){
  var parent = document.getElementById(parentId);
  NodeList.prototype.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;
  var children = parent.childNodes;
  children.forEach(function(item){
    var cln = item.cloneNode(true);
    parent.appendChild(cln);
  });
};

duplicateChildNodes("container");
```

```css
#container{
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 2px;
}
.square{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
  margin: 2px;
}
.red{
  background: red;
}

.green{
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="square red"></div>
  <div class="square green"></div>
</div>
```