# Create an editable copy of the dom object

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want to create a program that copies a HTML element as an object in order to later manipulate without changing the real DOM.

I am creating a simple multipurpose function that takes a string as an input and then looks through `document.body` to find the parent tag of that text. I am leveraging off the DOM parser in order to do this, but quickly found that I couldn't copy a HTML Node with `Object.create`.

Here's the code that's producing the problem:

```js
[...(Object.create(document.body).childNodes)]
```

I expected the result to be an editable copy of all the child nodes of `document.body` but instead got this error:

```
TypeError: Illegal invocation
    at Object.module.exports (bundle.js:6)
    at Object.1.../Util/parsers (bundle.js:10)
    at o (bundle.js:1)
    at r (bundle.js:1)
    at bundle.js:1
```

**Note:**
I am using browserify in order to bundle my code.

**Here is all of my (unfinished) code:**

main script:

```js
require('../Util/parsers')

module.exports = function(searchString, opts = {}) {
  const options = Object.assign({start: document.body, textOnly: true, parentLevel: 1, excludeTags: []}, opts)
  console.log([...(Object.create(options.start).childNodes)].mapFlat('childNodes', i => i instanceof NodeList ? [...i] : i))
}

try{
  module.exports()
} catch(e) {
  console.log(e)
}
```

Util/parsers:

```
Array.prototype.mapFlat = function(property, failed = i => i) {
  function runMap(retval, property, failed = i => i) {
    retval = retval.map(i => {
      if(i[property]) {
        const retval = [i, i[property]].flat(Infinity)
        delete i[property]
        return retval
      }

      return failed(i)
    }).flat(Infinity)

    return retval
  }

  let retval = this
  retval = runMap(retval, property, failed)

  while(retval.filter(i => i[property])[0]) {
    retval = runMap(retval, property, failed)
  }

  return retval
}
```

Comment: Look into https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode

Comment: I tried using cloneNode instead of Object.create and it didn't work, but I will try it as well as Object.create. @MarkSchultheiss

Comment: Just tried It, still got error.

Comment: You will need to work the child nodes, this may give you some ideas https://stackoverflow.com/q/47601722/125981

Comment: Without using Object.create there is not error, and I get a copy of the nodes, but I am still not able to edit them eg. delete properties. `cloneNode` also affects the real dom, which I don't want.